# import js file from public folder in a vue component (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

I need to import a file "js" from folder "public" in a vue component.

my Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

   import {myplugin} from "/public/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js";
   export default {
      name: "pageone"
   }
</script>
```

but i receive an error in compiling phase, can someone help me?

Comment: what is the error? Please attach error screenshot.

Comment: You need to use relative path, I assume. Something like `from '../../../public/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js'`

Comment: Why is there a `vendor` folder in your `public` folder?  `jquery` is most likely also present already (depending on which version of Laravel/Laravel UI you're using). Include/require jquery via npm. https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#working-with-scripts

Comment: Also, this `import {myplugin} from` is wrong. Should be something like `import * as jQuery from ...`

Answer (score 4):

(Although it's not a very good idea to place your libraries/packages to public folder when using compilers), if you really want to place it in public folder, you should use a relative_path.

```
import {myplugin} from "../../public/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js";
```

However, I'd install it as npm package and leverage laravel-mix for adding jquery in my build.

Answer (score -1):

No need to `import` it.

Just add a `<script src="/path/to/your.js">` into `head` section of `public/index.html`.